# Import error when running unit tests from terminal

Tags: python, unit-testing

Im running python 2.7 using pipenv on a Mac.

I have a unit test file called test_FileMerger.py in my tests directory. [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMKQr.png)

I am getting an ImportError when I try to run - `python -m unittest tests/test_FileMerger.py` (I have also tried the full path and I am getting the same error message.)

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

[Import by filename is not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAB6s.jpg)

When I run the test in Pycharm. The tests all pass. OK [Ran 7 tests in 0.051s OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO9pG.png)

Here is my unit test file.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from main.functions import LowerCaseColumns, RemoveColumn

class Test_Functions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_LowerCaseColumns_SingleDataFramePassed(mock_LowerCaseColumns):

    def test_LowerCaseColumns_MultipleDataFramesPassed(mock_LowerCaseColumns):

    def test_LowerCaseColumns_StringPassedReturnsAttributeError(mock_LowerCaseColumns):

    def test_LowerCaseColumns_IntPassedReturnsTypeError(mock_LowerCaseColumns):

    def test_LowerCaseColumns_BoolPassedReturnsTypeError(mock_LowerCaseColumns):

    def test_RemoveColumn_SingleColumnChanged(mock_RemoveColumn):

    def test_RemoveColumn_MultipleColumnsChanged(mock_RemoveColumn):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: which version of python is in Pycharm?

Comment: And in Your `PyCharm 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)` you use python in what version?

Comment: Try also run tests with python3. I gues it is installed in your system

Comment: In PyCharm 2019.2.4 (Community Edition) it is running on Python 3.8.1.

Comment: I just tried running "python3 -m unittest tests/test_FileMerger.py ". This time 1 test ran. Now i have a ModuleNotFoundError - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: In you system, you probably have following items: - `python2` which doens't support `Import by filename`, - `python3` which has not installed `pandas`, and `python3.8.1` inside Pycharm which has all requirements for running your tests. Sollution: install pandas for system's python3 (`pip3 install pandas`).

Comment: Problem solved thanks. Drop this in the answers for the vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you system, you probably have following items: - `python2` which doens't support `Import by filename`, - `python3` which has not installed `pandas`, and `python3.8.1` inside `Pycharm` which has all requirements for running your tests. Sollution: install `pandas` for system's `python3` (`pip3 install pandas`).

Answer (score 1):

Your sys.path is probably broken due to passing file names directly to unittest. Prefer passing module names, or using `python -munittest discover`.

Also your test methods make no sense, the first parameter of a method is `self`, and AFAIK they take no other parameters.

Comment: I have just tried running "python -m unittest discover". It ran 0 tests OK